# Regex pattern for matching ampersands between quotes in href attributes

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to write a script that encodes unencoded ampersands on a web page, including those embedded within query strings in URLs. I am trying to write a regex pattern to match each ampersand within href attributes, with the end goal being to swap them out with their HTML-encoded counterpart.

i.e. this:

```
href="http://example.com/blah?value&other&test"
```

would become:

```
href="http://example.com/blah?value&amp;other&amp;test"
```

I believe I'd need to make use of a lookahead (and/or perhaps a lookbehind?) insertion, but I don't understand well-enough how those work. Pages could potentially have multiple elements containing href attributes, so this needs to be able to match every ampersand within those tags.

Comment: How are you going to use the regex? Perhaps there's a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm using a proprietary utility that loads web pages for automated content scraping. Some of the pages in a feed I have access to are breaking due to a mistake in how they implemented their HTML encoding. I'm attempting to fix it on my side so that it parses as valid HTML in my tool.

Comment: What language is this being written in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a PCRE compliant language, you could use:

```
&(?!amp;)
```

...to match & that hasn't already been cleaned, and then replace with:

```
&amp;
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/lO6vK9/2

In order to make this work though, you need to split on the URL query `?` first, so that the resulting string you're cleaning up is actually, e.g., `value&other&test&amp;something`.

All of this said though, if your language has a built in URL encoding function, I'd recommend using that instead.

Comment: This is significantly more simple than what I was attempting, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Language you will use, but in almost every language there is a function for replacing letters or substring in strings.

For example in JavaScript:

```
var str = "hello world!";
var res = str.replace("world", "stackoverflow"); 
>> "hello stackoverflow!"
```